# MySQL Database Using ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, content-management-system

I have a website project developed in ASP.NET and i am using MySQL as database.

I want to develop a page that will accept information and an image and will store that information in database.

The same information should be available on different webpage from database. That page contains a layout with a picturebox and textboxes. I want to retrieve the information from mysql database and put it into specific location e.g. imagoe to picturebox and information to textboxes.

I have managed to complete insertion into database but stucked at retrieval in data binding to specific controls. Please help with example or refer me to any articles to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515911/how-to-use-mysql-with-asp-net

Comment: @drak : Thank you and yes, i saw this question already. Actually i already established connection to mysql using asp.net but dnt knw how to retrieve data.

Comment: anyone have an illustrated tutorial please ?